# Flutter: keep the same ratio for all images in list in expanded widget

Tags: flutter, image, dart, aspect-ratio, expanded

I have a list with an Image and Text in a Row. Both are in an `Expanded` widget to get the same width.

```
  Widget item(String value, String imageLocation) => Row(children: [
    Expanded(
        child: Image.asset(
      'assets/images/$imageLocation.png',
    )),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        value,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black54,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]);
```

That, everything is well drawn, but the images are too big.
Initially, all images have not the same size. And when I want to reduce it on screen by putting them in a Container with a definite size, many images are well reduced, but not the smallest which appear always big.
I also tried different fit properties, but without any success.

What I want is to reduce all images with the same ratio, so that they keep the same aspect as currently but smaller.

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just found a solution. `Image.asset` has a `scale` property. Change it to 2 or more did the job.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [`AspectRatio`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html) widget in Flutter, you can wrap your image widget with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Image` with the `AspectRatio` widget like this:

```
 AspectRatio(
   aspectRatio: 16/9,
    child: Image.asset(
  'assets/images/$imageLocation.png',
)),
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, no change. My problem is many image are linear and other more square. I think I should resize all pictures with an editor

Comment: can you try without Expanded widget ?

Comment: Strangely, everything disappears, even Text, without error message in logcat

Comment: I think it can't work because aspectRatio should be the same of the initial image, which is not easy. Thanks for your help.